# get selected value from @HtmlDropDown

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

So i get values for my drop down list but i wanted to get selected value from this dropdown. How to do this ?

Model:

```
  public partial class Region
{
    public int Id_regionu { get; set; }
    public string Nazwa { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
{


    private inzS9776Entities db = new inzS9776Entities();
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Regiony = new SelectList(db.Region,"Id_regionu", "Nazwa");
        return View();
    }
```

and View with dropdown:

```
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <legend>
        <h2>Wyszukaj wycieczkę</h2></legend><br/>
    <form action="">
        <div class="container">
            Wybierz kierunek:
            @Html.DropDownList("Regiony",null, String.Empty)<br />
            Data wyjazdu:
            <input class="date" type="date" name="startDate"><br><br>
        </div>
    </form>
```

`

Comment: Do you have some `<form>`, or a `post` of some kind? Or do you want to read the value from javascript?

Comment: i have form and i wanted to get data from database based on values from this form. I have edited the view with my from

Comment: Hmm,  seems you are missing some key elements. Check out this post, it might help you to understands the basics: http://blog.michaelckennedy.net/2012/01/20/building-asp-net-mvc-forms-with-razor/

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `<form action="">` to:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyActionName") {
    // ...  
    //here add to your dropdown and give it a name
    @Html.DropDownList("Regiony", null, String.Empty)
    // ...
}
```

The name attribute of your `<select>` element (dropdown list) will be "Regiony".

In your controller:

```
public ActionResult MyActionName(string Regiony) {
   // here Regiony variable contains the selected value.
   // ...
}
```

Comment: `Regiony` is the name and id! Why changing it in htmlAttributes?

Comment: Right, I took away the htmlAttributes, it makes it simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach which I take;

1) Retreive the items and store it in a list of SelectListItem.
2) Use the list of SelectListItem to assign it to a drop down list.
3) Use the model field to bind the drop down list with the selected value

View

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
    @{
        List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (LookupData l in Model.HeatingTypeData)
        {
            listItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = l.LookupDescription, Value = l.LookupCode });
        }
    }
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.HeatingType, listItems, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.HeatingType)
</div>
```

Models:
 The model (VoidProperty) used in the example contains the HeatingType as a List of LookupData and a method to get the list:

```
public List<LookupData> HeatingTypeData { get; set; }

    public static List<LookupData> GetHeatingType()
    {
        return LookupData.GetDataList("HeatingType").OrderBy(m => m.SortOrder).ToList();
    }
```

and then the LookupData:

```
public class LookupData : ILookup
    {
        public string LookupCode { get; set; }
        public string LookupDescription { get; set; }
        public int SortOrder { get; set; }

        public static List<LookupData> GetDataList(string LookupGroup)
        {
            DBContexts.VoidsDBContext context = new DBContexts.VoidsDBContext();
            var Params = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "LookupGroup", Value = LookupGroup };
            return context.Database.SqlQuery<LookupData>("p_LookupList @LookupGroup", Params).ToList();
        }
    }
```

The controller returns the view and pass an instance of the model;

```
VoidProperty _property = new VoidProperty();
......
......
_property.HeatingTypeData = VoidProperty.GetHeatingType();
......
return View(_property);
```